# Безопасный запуск php файла

Tags: php, безопасность

Здравствуйте. Делаю что-то вроде сайта с редактором PHP кода. При нажатии на клавишу просмотра, у меня в специальной директории создаётся папка с уникальным id и в ней файл с самим php кодом (пример: `/_projects/6dfh78d76dfg87/index.php`). Дальше эта страничка открывается в `iframe`.

Так вот к проблеме: столкнулся с проблемой безопасности. С созданного файла можно редактировать любой файл сайта (.htaccess и другие файлы сайта). Я набросал пару вариантов, как можно ограничить доступ к файлам своего сайта:

1. Защитить изменение и удаление важных файлов *(но тут недостаток: можно редактировать файлы чужого "проекта")*
2. Запретить файлам с директории `/_projects/{ID}/` обращаться к
   файлам, которые находятся вне папки *{ID}*
3. Запретить некоторые функции в PHP
4. Скрыть директории и файлы от функций таких, как `scandir`,
   `dirname`...
5. Проверять PHP файл на наличие запрещённых функций

Но не знаю, как можно осуществить эти варианты. Подскажите, как можно их осуществить или кто-то знает вариант получше? Буду очень признателен. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: А не вариант выбрасывать `../`  - такие пути и сравнивать с путями? а вообще вот если посмотреть на http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/, они при выполнении скрипта запрещают функции такие как opendir и так далее, в php.ini : disable_functions =

Comment: В любом варианте вы по сути предоставляете полный доступ к ресурсам вашего сервера, так что, даже если вы запретите редактировать чужие файлы, тогда просто станут грузить проц на 100% майнингом биткоинов :)

Comment: @andreymal, там в htaccess можно ограничить степень и время загрузки скрипта. Я просто возьму и запрещу скрипты, которые грузятся больше 30 секунд (к примеру)

Comment: За htaccess очень быстро убегут и станут юзать, например, Python, до которого htaccess никак не дотянется :) Ну или в крайнем случае напишут такой скрипт, который будет работать ровно 29.9 секунд и каждые полминуты перезапускать его :)

Comment: @andreymal, к htaccess я вообще закрою доступ всем. А вот с такой перспективой проблема. Я склоняюсь к ответу *Mikhail Vaysman*, так как контейнер не даст такого вытворять..

Comment: htaccess даже трогать не будут, мимо него просто убегут) В самом худшем случае найдут лазейку для загрузки ssh-ключа и станут подключаться к серверу непосредственно, вообще без браузера мимо веб-сервера (я так делал, да). Самый лучший вариант — таки грамотно настроить и ограничить контейнер, да

Comment: @andreymal, ну, посмотрим на другие варианты, может будут лучше, может кто сочинил своё "ноу хау" :)

Comment: посмотрите опцию php.ini open_basedir. php скрипт ничего за пределами каталогов, указанных в ней сделать не может. правда есть проблема, из htaccess ее установить нельзя. только в httpd.conf значит надо будет под все папки генерить разделы в конфиге и указывать в каждом буквально только /tmp и сам каталог со скриптом

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Самым надежным вариантом будет запуск кода внутри контейнера (например, Docker) с настроенным [SECCOMP](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/seccomp/) и selinux [SELinux](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux). При этом вы можете запускать любой код, а не только PHP.

Код может делать почти всё, что угодно и ограничить его можно как угодно.

Презентация о том как можно обезопасить Docker container: [Слайды](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1Fs32kRG2FhbeO_-WdYSdP2dauepeo_VV5R69Q_xZeYo/pub?start=false&loop=false&delayms=3000&slide=id.g167dd20c9e_3_14) и [Видео](https://youtu.be/wKT191Ak9fA)

Comment: Не подскажете какую-то ссылочку по этому поводу? В этой безопасности ничего не знаю )

Comment: я обновил ответ. добавил ссылки на документацию и презентацию.

Comment: Сложновато. Ладно, если никто не ответит "проще", отмечу как правильные, спасибо :)

Comment: да. это сложное решение, но одно из надежнейших. и не надо думать над анализом самого кода.

Comment: Вы простите, я за ответ возложу премию, и если тогда уже не будет лучше ответа, то вы получите +100 в репутацию )

Comment: без проблем  - это ваш вопрос :)

Comment: Это самая большая пробка на пути создания моего редактора. Хотелось бы найти штопор по проще, что бы её вытащить

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51261/discussion-between-mikhail-vaysman-and-yuri).

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman, прошу прошения ... а где в вопросе шла речь о Линуксе? Если таковой речи не было - пожалуйста, указывайте все подробности вашего "местячкокого" решения.

Comment: Поздравляю с приобретением :)

Answer (score 10):

@Yuri, судя по пути из вашего примера - речь идет о *nix системе. А там все просто, самое главное - обозначить "бизнес логику" вашего проекта. Иными словами обозначить "кто может что".

- для PHP выделяем отдельного "пользователя"
- обозначаем ему права

Таким образом он не сможет сделать то, что ему не позволено.

**Важно**

Важно права десять раз продумать. Пример. Пользователю дано право/возможность создавать любой файл. Пользователь создает файл с расширением `.php`... а потом возьмет и его исполнит. Вы понимаете, что он сможет сделать все, что в "доступности" прав пользователя, имеющего доступ к ресурсам *.php

**Таки образом**

Используя встроенные средства *nix вы ограничиваете множество действий, которые пользователь может выполнить в принципе. А в своем скрипте - вы "предусматриваете" нужный вам функционал. Для обеспечения **безопасности** - этого хватит вполне.

Понятие "любой файл" нужно четко определить. Путем, маской, зарезервированным названием...

Хороший принцип "запретить все, потом нужное  разрешить". Это ваш случай.

Comment: Что делать если нужно безопасно выполнять пользовательские php скрипты? К примеру если  делается аналог Project Euler.

Comment: Для этого нужно обозначить критерии требуемой безопасности.

Answer (score 6):

На мой взгляд самый простой способ это просто проверять токен и id пользователя при редактировании файла. У вас это решение номер 2. 
1 Авторизоваться
2 получить список файлов и папок  /_projects/{ID}/
3 Если пользователь может ввести путь самостоятельно, то парсить путь и сопоставлять  {ID} папки и {ID} пользователя

Как ещё один вариант: Сгенерировать уникальную папку владельца, путь к которой будет  сложно подобрать, например, KMnwVmc6Uz7zsJ4w, этот вариант менее безопасный. Так как редактирование вы не закрываете, а просто полагаетесь, что папку никто не найдет

Answer (score 5):

Выполняйте скрипты централизованно, через `include` в собственном сценарии роутинга.
Там Вы можете через директиву ограничить доступ к файловой системе для каждого пользователя ресурса:

```
ini_set('open_basedir', $userProjectDir);
```

Выше `$userProjectDir` в текущем сеансе исполнения подняться не удастся. 
Путь к директории должен быть абсолютным.

Далее, есть ещё одна проблема - доступ к `localhost`. Пользовательский скрипт должен иметь доступ только к разрешённым портам. Этого можно достичь либо ограничением пользователя среды исполнения (php-fpm, apache, ..) в [iptables](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/block-outgoing-network-access-for-a-single-user-from-my-server-using-iptables.html), либо виртуализацией. Виртуализация так же позволяет ограничивать ресурсы машины по отношению к пользователю.