# Запуск сайта из Docker-образа VS запуск c традиционными средствами (uWSGI, Nginx, Apache)

Tags: администрирование, веб-сервер, docker, развертывание, сборка

Имеется веб-сайт на Django, на боевом сервере для запуска использую связку uWSGI/Nginx, локальная разработка - virtualenv/dev-сервер Django

Решил пощупать Docker-технологию для запуска приложений и в процессе чтения появился вопрос.

Запуск боевого сайта из Docker-образа проще, чем указанным способом (uWSGI/Nginx)? Помимо запуска сайта, на боевом сервере проект также собирается webpack'ом, минифицируется код, преобразуется некоторая статика и пр.

P.S. Заранее извиняюсь за определение "традиционные средства запуска сайта", у всех могут быть разные вкусы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да. Запуск проще. Грубо говоря все сведется к одной команде `docker run <имя образа> [<дополнительные параметры>]`. Сама хост-система может быть "голой" - без каких либо дополнительных утилит, библиотек, сервисов - только Docker.

Comment: Чтобы не множить бестолковые темы, задам вопрос здесь. Внутри контейнера работать от рута? Все равно процесс изолирован

Comment: настоятельно рекомендую выбрать не привилегированного пользователя в контейнере и еще ограничить контейнер в правах. вот тут можете посмотреть мой ответ об ограничении контейнера http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/610945/215007

Comment: читаю презентацию и сразу назревает непонимание. как так? контейнер же изолирован, все процессы внутри него, смысл заводить пользователя?

Comment: я, пожалуй, дочитаю и если что-то не пойму, создам отдельную тему

Answer (score 1):

Сразу предупреждаю, я не профессионал. Дам только общее представление, могу в чем-то ошибиться.

### Суть

Традиционно вы берете сервер (железный или виртуальную машину), на нем разворачиваете свой сайт, устанавливаете нужные зависимости, конфигурируете.

С докером вы берете чистый образ (image) операционной системы, делаете почти всё то же самое в нем, пакуете в новый образ, отправляете его в специальное хранилище- registry.

Потом при установке этот образ скачивается  из registry и запускается в виртуальной машине.

### Достоинства

- Вы каждый раз устанавливаете на свежий образ, у вас сервера-фениксы, а не снежинки (тут позже появится ссылка на блог Мартина Фаулера ).
- Образ создается однократно и используется много раз. Развертывание готового образа происходит очень быстро. Вы можете быстро реагировать и масштабировать сайт (разумеется, это надо будет настроить)
- Ваши тестировщики тестируют **точно то же**, что потом пойдет на production, а не что-то похожее.
- Поскольку в registry хранятся и старые версии, в случае внезапного факапа вы отказываетесь легко (ну, легче чем традиционно)

### Недостатки

- Напишу позже на свежую голову. Но они есть, они у всего есть.

В целом всё это касается не только докера. Обязательно поищите и прочитайте про 12-факторные приложения (12-factor applications). (Тут тоже ссылку добавлю позже)

Comment: _Потери производительности на виртуализацию._ какую виртуализацию вы имеете ввиду? Записать на диск можно.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman значит я всё-таки наврал. ) Спасибо за замечание. Поправлю позже, сейчас слишком устал. Или вы поправьте, как считаете нужным, не буду  возражать. )